# Values in union in C

Tags: c, unions

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{  
    union a
    {
       int i;
       char ch[2];
    };
    union a u;
    u.ch[0] = 0;
    u.ch[1] = 2;
    u.ch[2] = 0;
    u.ch[3] = 0;
    printf("%d\n",u.i);   
    return 0;
}
```

In this program, if the size of integer is given to be 4 bytes, then how is it that the output will be 512? We will see that out of the 4 bytes, the first two bytes will be occupied by `0` and `0`. Then why am I getting that as the output?

Comment: Your program causes undefined bahavior; the left two bytes of `u.i` wasn't initialized.

Comment: 1) `int` is probably 32 bit on your architecture. 2) `ch` is only 2 bytes wide, 3) you assigned `u.ch[1]` three times in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the code you have posted is in error and that you meant to initialize the other two bytes of the `int` as in the corrected code below, because otherwise there was very little chance you would get `512` as output.

In this case, because most Intel machines are little-endian, you have set the third  most significant byte to `2` and every other byte to 0. Because `2 * 256 = 512`, you get `512` as output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{  
    union a
    {
       int i;
       char ch[4];
    };
    union a u;
    u.ch[0] = 0;
    u.ch[1] = 2;
    u.ch[2] = 0;
    u.ch[3] = 0;
    printf("%d\n",u.i);   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ikh, Actually, in this case, it does not matter whether it is `ch[2]` or `ch[4]`, because the `int` will force the memory to be allocated for 4 bytes regardless (we assume `int` is 4 bytes on this platform).

Comment: @merline2011 But the code is against standard, although assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`, isn't it?

Comment: @ikh You are most likely correct and it is a one character change so I'll go ahead and change it.  In the future though it is better to make such claims only with a reference to a specific part of a specific standard though.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). The byte order inside some `int` is processor dependent.